# Golang and JWT - Simple Logout

Tags: go, jwt, token, logout, jwt-go

I'm currently working on an API and after a bit of time, I now understand how to use JWT in Go to get a token. With this token, I can keep a user connected but, how can I logout from the client application?

Here is my `token.go` code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "time"
)

const (
    tokenEncodeString = "something"
)

func createToken(user User) (string, error) {
    // create the token                                                                                                                                                                                  
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)

    // set some claims                                                                                                                                                                                   
    token.Claims["username"] = user.Username;
    token.Claims["password"] = user.Password;
    token.Claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix()

    //Sign and get the complete encoded token as string                                                                                                                                                  
    return (token.SignedString([]byte(tokenEncodeString)))
}

func parseToken(unparsedToken string) (bool, string) {
    token, err := jwt.Parse(unparsedToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte(tokenEncodeString), nil
    })

    if err == nil && token.Valid {
            return true, unparsedToken
    } else {
            return false, ""
    }
}
```

After research, I found out that I can use a black list, but I really want to know if it's possible with something easier, like the code above.

I also want to find a solution that works with the memory used by the JWT process. Someone who disconnects/connects himself all the time has to have only one token for each session, not one for him and a hundred in a given black list.

Comment: JWT logouts are generally done on the client side. Issuing an "empty" token could serve to do the same thing.

Comment: a couple of things, it's a pretty bad idea to store a password in a jwt token, though they're signed they can still be easily base64 decoded. For the rest of the question, generally this is something fairly easy to solve with a session id that you expire server-side when you want to invalidate the token.

Comment: Ok I will change that, thank for your messages ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: Don't (ever) put sensitive credentials in the token. They are not encrypted, and you shouldn't need to do that.

To note:

- JWTs are stateless: you issue one, and it lives as long as you have allowed/are validating against on the server.
- You could issue a new JWT with an expiry of 'now', but the old JWT would still be valid (i.e. a security risk).
- Read through http://jwt.io/introduction/

If you need control over expiring access tokens after issuance, then you should implement a server-side scheme, which would allow you to expire tokens directly. The user would only hold an ID that references the server-side store.